# Stata. How to use if statement with sum()?

Tags: if-statement, sum, stata

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
    forval i = 1/51 {

    // number of households
    by hhid, sort: gen nvals = _n==1
    count if (nvals & stateID == `i')
    local stateTotalHH = r(N)

        local avPersonHH`i' = sum(numper)/`stateTotalHH' if(nvals & stateID ==`i')
        drop nvals 
}
```

Everything works fine except `if` is not allowed with `sum()`. How can I estimate the total or the sum of all values in  `numper` variable for each state and at household level?

ps:

1. I cannot use `collapse numper, by(stateID)` because I have other estimations
2. also, I cannot do the following: `duplicates drop hhid, force`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem does not even call for `sum()` with `if`, so it is best to start at the beginning.

Reconstructing your problem, which is not well explained,

1. You have observations for individuals within households (identifier `hhid`) within 50 states of the USA and the District of Columbia (identifier `stateID`).
2. You have a variable `numper`, the number of persons per household, and you want the average per state.
3. Observations are repeated for each individual in a household, so it is necessary to use just one observation per household.

You can tag each household once by

```
  egen tag = tag(hhid)
```

The average as a new variable would be

```
 egen avPersonHH = mean(numper/tag), by(stateID)
```

Stata is going to average `numper/tag` which variously will be `numper/1` and `numper/0`; the missings from the latter division will just be ignored, which is what is wanted.

That variable is repeated for each household. To see just one value for each `stateID`,

```
 tabdisp stateID, cell(avPersonHH)
```

What is wrong with your code? Here is a partial list:

a. No loop is required.

b. If it were, the statement `by hhid, sort: gen nvals = _n==1` should not be repeated.

c. `sum()` is a function for cumulative sums across observations, not what you want here.

d. The line

```
  local avPersonHH`i' = sum(numper)/`stateTotalHH' if(nvals & stateID ==`i')
```

would at best calculate one number, but the `if` condition is misplaced. `if` whatever `local` ... often makes sense in Stata, but putting `if` on the right of a `local` definition only makes sense for manipulating text containing commands.

Your comment on this line misses these basic misconceptions, c. and d.

e. You were aiming to have collected 51 values of averages in as many local macros, but still need to put them somewhere useful.

f. Separate calculation of totals and numbers is not required, as you can get Stata to calculate the mean for you.

(LATER) This code plays along step by step with your aversion to using `collapse` and `duplicates`, the grounds for which are not stated. But most experienced Stata users would be happy to use brute force:

```
   duplicates drop hhid, force 
   collapse numper, by(stateID)
```

and then `merge` back. That solution is not only direct, but also uses fewer idiosyncratic Stata details, which can take time to figure out.

Comment: Thank you Dr. Cox. I was aware of the `duplicates drop hhid, force 
   collapse...` method, but i wanted to avoid it because i have other estimations in the same `.do` file...and i wanted to put everything in one loop. `merge`ing huge data sets takes much time...in economics people plays with variables and the results :) , so timing is a big deal.

Comment: It's your problem, but this doesn't match most experience elsewhere. The real time cost implied by your strategy includes the coding time trying to avoid the `merge`. What you were trying to code was a loop over states, which could only slow things down. Many people will spend 2 hours coding because something takes 2 minutes and they prefer 2 seconds. That's a good idea only if you are going to do that same stuff repeatedly.